# Cross MySQL Database Same Machine INSRET SYNTAX Fail

Tags: mysql, database

i have working to migrate the different mysql database in the same machine. I want to copy all the rows in table called ms_barang from fist database to another database.

The columns is little bit different so, i create join table and inserting to second table in different database.

My SQL Syntax is

```
 INSERT INTO sre.`ms_barang`(`idms_kodebarang`,`nama`,`gudang`,`jenis`,`packing`) 
 VALUES (
     SELECT sr.mb.`idms_kodebarang` AS 'idms_kodebarang', sr.mb.`nama` AS 'nama', sr.mb.`gudang` AS 'gudang', sr.mb.`jenis` AS 'jenis', sr.md.`packing` 'packing'
     FROM sr.ms_barangjadi mb JOIN sr.ms_daftarbarang md
     WHERE sr.mb.`idms_kodebarang` = sr.md.`idms_kodebarang`
  );
```

as you can see, there are two database called SR and SRE

but it keeps telling that the syntax is fail. where is the error?

Comment: can you post the entire error message?

Comment: <e>Query: insert into sre.`ms_barang`(`idms_kodebarang`,`nama`,`gudang`,`jenis`,`packing`) values ( select sr.mb.`idms_kodebarang` as 'idm...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select sr.mb.`idms_kodebarang` as 'idms_kodebarang', sr.mb.`nama` as 'nama', sr.' at line 3

@BeNdErR

Comment: In MSSQL, that's not how VALUES works. I know MySQL goes its own way, but you could try omitting VALUES(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the VALUES keyword,[**Doc**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
    INSERT INTO sre.`ms_barang`(`idms_kodebarang`,`nama`,`gudang`,`jenis`,`packing`) 
  (
     SELECT sr.mb.`idms_kodebarang` AS 'idms_kodebarang', sr.mb.`nama` AS 'nama', sr.mb.`gudang` AS 'gudang', sr.mb.`jenis` AS 'jenis', sr.md.`packing` 'packing'
     FROM sr.ms_barangjadi mb JOIN sr.ms_daftarbarang md
     WHERE sr.mb.`idms_kodebarang` = sr.md.`idms_kodebarang`
  );
```